# I'm having a double click issue activating jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click

I've found similar answers that solve the double click issue when first calling a jQuery function, usually from having a click() function inside another click() or missing the $(document).ready. None of these solutions have solved the issue for me. When the page first loads I have to click once on the button and then a second time to activate the function. Oddly, this is only an issue in Firefox and it performs correctly in Chrome.

HTML:

```
<li class="nav-item">
<a id="resize-fix" class="nav-link full-button" alt="Full-Width Resize" title="Full-Width Resize"><i class="lnr lnr-frame-expand"></i></a>
</li>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if ($.cookie('fullscreen') == "yes") {
        $('#resize-fix').find('i').removeClass('lnr-frame-expand');
        $('#resize-fix').find('i').addClass('lnr-frame-contract');
        $('.container').addClass('box-full');
    }

    // When the icon is clicked
    $("#resize-fix").click(function () {
        // Check the current cookie value
        // If the cookie is empty or set to no, then add fullscreen
        if ($.cookie('fullscreen') == "undefined" || $.cookie('fullscreen') == "no") {
            // Set cookie value to yes
            $.cookie('fullscreen','yes', {expires: 7, path: '/'});
            // Add the class to the container
            $(this).find('i').toggleClass('lnr-frame-expand lnr-frame-contract');
            $('.container').addClass('box-full');
        }
        // If the cookie was already set to yes then remove it
        else {
            $.cookie('fullscreen','no',  {expires: 7, path: '/'});
            // Remove the class from the container
            $(this).find('i').toggleClass('lnr-frame-expand lnr-frame-contract');
            $('.container').removeClass('box-full');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: could you reproduce the problem in a snippet or fiddle?

Comment: Well, I tried? I created a fiddle but it doesn't work. I'm a noob. https://jsfiddle.net/Budmaniak/xpvt214o/136294/.

I'm also checking some of the answers in this Stack question, but no such luck for me yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246065/javascript-onclick-needs-to-be-clicked-twice-for-function-to-run

Comment: Oy, I solved my own problem. Changed `$.cookie('fullscreen')=="undefined"` to `!$.cookie('fullscreen')`. That fixed the double click.

Comment: How do I pull this question down? Or do i?